# Best practice for local variable scope in a C++ callback

Tags: c++

I have a functioning C++ callback function, triggered by a user 'mouse down' event.  (The IDE is VS2010.)

With each call, I'd like to increment a simple count variable that is local to the callback's scope.  Simply put, what is the 'best practices' way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any opinions or directives.

Comment: If you want this variable only in the callback function, then a static variable is what you want.

Comment: you could use a static variable, but be very carefully about its use in general

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace your callback function with a functor - they can store state. An example functor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Functor
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> m_count;

public:
    Functor()
    :    m_count(new int(0))
    {}

    void operator()()
    {
        ++(*m_count);
        // do other stuff...
    }

    int count() const
    {
        return *m_count;
    }
};

template <typename F>
void f(F callback)
{
    // do stuff
    callback();
    // do other stuff
}

int main()
{
    Functor callback;
    f(callback);
    f(callback);
    std::cout << callback.count();    // prints 2
    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of a `shared_ptr` inside the functor - this is because `f` has a local copy of the functor (note the pass-by-value) and you want that copy to share its `int` with the functor to which you have access. Note also that `f` has to take its argument by value, since you want to support all callables, and not just functors.

Comment: is should vote you down for trivially using a shared pointer in the example? A simple int member variable would more than suffice

Comment: @maress: Read the explanation first and then decide.

Comment: furthermore, the recipient of the callback could be an object requiring copy semantics (e.g. something that stores all callbacks in a standard library container)

Comment: Thanks, Stuart, your functor code is thoughtfully complete and your explanation does nicely make the argument for using this approach rather than a 'simple' static variable.  However, I appreciate Geoffroy's reminder that a static variable is also a viable option.